# Environment variable, referencing another environment variable

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I found, that [`Rapid Environment Editor`](http://www.rapidee.com/en/download) program, displays some variables as of type "expandable string". Such variables can refer another variables, for example

```
JAVA_HOME_45 = ...
JAVA_HOME = %JAVA_HOME_45%
PATH = %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

The problem is that such variables are not working from time to time.

The question is: at which level are they implemented? Is this Windows feature? If yes, then how to activate/deactivate/debug it?

Comment: from my experience, using variables like in your example works reliable, if you edit them via the Windows standard tool. Maybe the linked editor is buggy. It's not a standard tool, but third party tool.

Comment: I had this exact same problem.  The reason the references sometimes worked was because sometimes I was running (powershell) elevated.  I was setting (via script pointing to different versions) JAVA_HOME at the user level and referencing JAVA_HOME in my PATH variable at both the machine and user level.  Because the machine level didn't have JAVA_HOME set, and because it was referenced in it's PATH, it wouldn't expand.  Thus, when running elevated it failed, when non-elevated, it succeeded.

Comment: I have similar observation regarding RapidEE. It may be connected with accidental change of variable type from "Expandable String" to "String" which is silently triggered with hotkey F6.

Answer (score 3):

I just tested it and it works (like JimHawkins said) with the standard environment variables editor.

This means that it is a Windows feature and it should always be turned on.

You can "debug" it if you open a Console and enter: echo %PATH%.